# Can some operators in Python not be overloaded properly?

Tags: python

I am studying Scott Meyers' *More Effective C++*. Item 7 advises to never overload `&&` and `||`, because their short-circuit behavior cannot be replicated when the operators are turned into function calls <sub>(*or is this no longer the case?*)</sub>.

As operators can also be [overloaded in Python](http://fiber-space.de/wordpress/2009/04/16/universal-set-in-python/), I am curious whether this situation exists there as well. *Is there any operator in Python (2.x, 3.x) that, when overridden, cannot be given its original meaning?*

Here is an example of 'original meaning'

```
class MyInt {
    public: 
    MyInt operator+(MyInt &m) {
           return MyInt(this.val + m.val);
    };
    int val; 
    MyInt(int v) : val(v){} 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Exactly the same rationale applies to Python. You shouldn't (and can't) overload `and` and `or`, because their short-circuiting behavior cannot be expressed in terms of functions. `not` isn't permitted either - I guess this is because there's no guarantee that it will be invoked at all.

As pointed out in the comments, the [proposal](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0335/) to allow the overloading of logical `and` and `or` was officially rejected.

Comment: Exactly. To elaborate: There are special methods `__and__` and `__or__`  that you can overload, but they refer to the bitwise operations `&` and `|`. These are sometimes overloaded to mimic logical operations, such as in NumPy and Pandas. There was a proposal [PEP335](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0335/) to allow the overloading of logical `and` and `or`. It was rejected.

Answer (score 1):

The assignment operator can also not be overloaded.

```py
class Thing: ...

thing = Thing()
thing = 'something else'
```

There is nothing you can override in Thing to change the behavior of the = operator.

(You can overload property assignment though.)

Answer (score 0):

In Python, all object methods that represent operators are treated "equal": their precedences are described in the language model, and there is no conflict with overriding any.

But  both C++ "&&" and "||" - in Python "and" and "or" -  are not available in Python as object methods to start with - they check for the object truthfulness, though - which is defined by `__bool__`. If `__bool__`is not implemented, Python check for a `__len__` method, and check if its output is zero, in which case the object's truth value is `False`. In all other cases its truth value is `True`. That makes it for any semantic problems that would arise from combining overriding with the short-circuiting behavior.

Note one can override `&` and `|` by implementing `__and__` and `__or__` with no problems.

As for the other operators, although not directly related, one should just take care with `__getattribute__`  - the method called when retrieving *any*  attribute from an object (we normally don't mention it as an operator) - including calls from within itself. The `__getattr__` is also in place, and is just invoked at the end of the attribute search chain, when an attribute is not found.